# Position of favorite tags list

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-watching, advertising

I'm getting more and more annoyed with my favorite tags list. It appears just below two ad blocks. Everytime when the question page loads one of the ads loads a little slower then the rest of the page. Multiple times a day the favorite tags list is moving downwards just at the moment I want to make a selection.

Simple request: Could it be moved to be positioned above the ad blocks?

[image: Moving the tags list]

Comment: I agree. I'd also wish it would be at a more top level of the side bar.

Comment: I also agree but if we end up that we have to pay because the ads don't bring in enough money (due to less clicks) to keep the site operational I can live with this annoyance...

Comment: @Rene, I agree. An alternative could be to give the ad block a fixed height, whether it loads or not, to avoid the tags from jumping down.

Comment: Another solution is simply to use a bookmark to directly target the link you get to while clicking on the tag in your favorites list.

Comment: Alternatively, at least add the size of the ads to the html, so we get a properly sized placeholder until we have the picture.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It is a broken alternatives IMO. First, some people (like me) does not use bookmarks. Second, if we have to do this on SO, ServerFault, Programmers, Reddit, YourFavoriteSiteWithTags... 
An alternative could be to put the block between the ad and the SO Careers block (which is not an ad for me btw).

Comment: Hmmm... mine are on top

Comment: Knew I'd seen this before.

Comment: This is the work around I'm currently using: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276130/57475, just hides the ads and careers panels by overriding the css with a browser plugin.